# Creating Column based on multiple column values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science

If I have a df as below:

```
ID | Car | Plane | Tank | Scooter | Misc  | Day
4    Yes    No      Yes    No        32     Mon
2    No     No      No     No        22     Tues
1    Yes    No      No     No        11     Wed
```

How can I create a new column that says True or False if there is a value of Yes or No in any of the columns that is Car or Plane or Tank or Scooter? Thanks

Comment: `df['new_column'] = df[['Car','Plane','Scooter']].eq("Yes").any(1)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.iloc` to determine which column you want to use for your check. And you can. use the `.any(1)` to see if any of the value is a `'Yes'` or `'No'`

The code will be as follows. I added a 4th row with 'Maybe' as a value to show you that the record does not meet the 'Yes', 'No' condition.

```
#created the DataFrame with a few sample values
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[4,2,1,3],
                   'Car':['Yes','No','Yes','Maybe'],
                   'Plane':['No','No','No','Maybe'],
                   'Tank':['Yes','No','No','Maybe'],
                   'Scooter':['No','No','No','Maybe'],
                   'Misc':[32,22,11,44],
                   'Day':['Mon','Tues','Wed','Thu']})

#printing the full DataFrame to make sure the values are as expected
print(df)

#the iloc option can be used to filter the columns you want to checked
#printing it out for you to see which ones are being used for selection 
print(df.iloc[:,1:-2])

#if you want to check for 'Yes' or 'No', then use |. If either then it will set to 'True'
#if you want to check for only for 'Yes', then you dont need the second part
df['Check'] = ((df.iloc[:,1:-2] == 'Yes') | (df.iloc[:,1:-2] == 'No')).any(1)

#the DataFrame will have the new column with True or False
print (df)
```

The Output are as follows:

**Initial DataFrame:**

```
   ID    Car  Plane   Tank Scooter  Misc   Day
0   4    Yes     No    Yes      No    32   Mon
1   2     No     No     No      No    22  Tues
2   1    Yes     No     No      No    11   Wed
3   3  Maybe  Maybe  Maybe   Maybe    44   Thu
```

**Filtered Columns from the DataFrame are:**

```
     Car  Plane   Tank Scooter
0    Yes     No    Yes      No
1     No     No     No      No
2    Yes     No     No      No
3  Maybe  Maybe  Maybe   Maybe
```

**Final Results for you to use:**

```
   ID    Car  Plane   Tank Scooter  Misc   Day  Check
0   4    Yes     No    Yes      No    32   Mon   True
1   2     No     No     No      No    22  Tues   True
2   1    Yes     No     No      No    11   Wed   True
3   3  Maybe  Maybe  Maybe   Maybe    44   Thu  False
```

If your condition changes to the following:

If any value in 'Car', 'Plane', 'Tank', 'Scooter' = 'Yes', set 'Check' to True. For all other cases, set 'Check' to False.

Then, the earlier code can be simplified as follows:

```
df['Check'] = (df.iloc[:,1:-2] == 'Yes').any(1)
```

**The output for this will be as follows:**

```
   ID    Car  Plane   Tank Scooter  Misc   Day  Check
0   4    Yes     No    Yes      No    32   Mon   True
1   2     No     No     No      No    22  Tues  False
2   1    Yes     No     No      No    11   Wed   True
3   3  Maybe  Maybe  Maybe   Maybe    44   Thu  False
```

In case your DataFrame is not structured with Car, Plane, Tank, and Scooter next to each other, you can always put these into a list and use that to filter and check.

For example, if your DataFrame is as shown below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[4,2,1,3],
                   'Car':['Yes','No','Yes','Maybe'],
                   'Plane':['No','No','No','Maybe'],
                   'Misc':[32,22,11,44],
                   'Tank':['Yes','No','No','Maybe'],
                   'Day':['Mon','Tues','Wed','Thu'],
                   'Scooter':['No','No','No','Maybe']})
```

Then it will look like this

```
   ID    Car  Plane  Misc   Tank   Day Scooter
0   4    Yes     No    32    Yes   Mon      No
1   2     No     No    22     No  Tues      No
2   1    Yes     No    11     No   Wed      No
3   3  Maybe  Maybe    44  Maybe   Thu   Maybe
```

You wont be able to use the `.iloc[:,1:-2]`. Instead you can put all the columns into a list and use that as follows.

```
cols = ['Car','Plane','Tank','Scooter']

print(df[cols])

df['Check'] = (df[cols] == 'Yes').any(1)
```

This will give you the same result as the iloc option we discussed earlier

**Output will be:**

```
   ID    Car  Plane  Misc   Tank   Day Scooter  Check
0   4    Yes     No    32    Yes   Mon      No   True
1   2     No     No    22     No  Tues      No  False
2   1    Yes     No    11     No   Wed      No   True
3   3  Maybe  Maybe    44  Maybe   Thu   Maybe  False
```

Answer (score 1):

the following code should give True in case any of the columns have a 'Yes' value per row

```
df['new col'] = df[['Car', 'Plane', 'Tank', 'Scooter']].apply(lambda x: any(x == 'Yes'), axis = 1)
```